# Chrome игнорирует настройку "Всегда указывать место для скачивания"

Tags: google-chrome

Мой хром игнорирует переключатель "Всегда указывать место для скачивания" в настройках. Не важно включен он или отключен, если я жму `Ctrl+S` при открытии картинки в отдельном окне (или видео файла например) - мне предлагается выбор, в какое место сохранить этот файл.

Хочу жать `Ctrl+S` и сохранять файлы без вопросов.

Это как-то фиксится?

p.s. В яндекс браузере такой проблемы нет, а вот в хромиуме, который я открыл прямиком из архива - та же проблема (можете отписать о своей версии браузера chrome и о том, существует ли проблема у вас)

Comment: http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: @PashaPash в багрепорт я написал ещё до создания вопроса здесь. Через возможности самого браузера (О браузере / Сообщить о проблеме).

Comment: Я не уверен что это ошибка. Потому что Ctrl-S - это Сохранить **Как...**, что по-умолчанию подразумевает диалог о том, куда это сохранять.

Comment: @Alekcvp а что тогда, по вашему, должна менять настройка "Всегда указывать место для скачивания"?

Comment: В яндекс браузере при включенной настройке - предлагается место сохранения файла, при выключенной, сохраняется в папку загрузок, без дополнительных вопросов

Comment: @TryCatch, менять поведение при _скачивании_ файлов по ссылкам, очевидно же. Скачивание файла и сохранение открытой страницы/изображения - _в моём понимании_ это разные вещи. Яндекс браузер же - это вещь в себе, и их понимание может отличаться от моего (и разработчиков хромиума). Это одна из причин почему я использую хром, а не ЯБ :)

Comment: Какая у вас версия хрома?(chrome://settings/help)

Comment: @AdamHodovanets Версия 62.0.3202.94 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)

Comment: Вряд ли это баг. Описание страниц помощи "загрузка файла" разное. В яндексе есть ["умная" строка с кнопкой сохранения открытых файлов и страница помощи с описанием сохранения файлов открытых для просмотра](https://yandex.ru/support/browser/working-with-files/download-files.html#upload-file-open-viewing), в гугле нет. Вероятнее всего в яндексе есть надстройка для сохранения файлов по ctrl s, связанная с кнопкой "сохранить" умной строкой.

Comment: Ради примера [ссылка на скачивание картинки](https://yandex.ru/images/today?size=1920x1200) будет автоматически сохранять файл в обоих браузерах. А если вы включите "Всегда указывать место для скачивания", то перед скачиванием будет диалог для выбора директории для скачивания.

Comment: @Alex ладно, я понял. Если ванильный хром нельзя настроить так, как я хочу - буду использовать другие браузеры.

Comment: @TryCatch как вариант Вы можете написать свое расширение для хрома или написать в тп предложение о реализации такой функции. p.s.:  предположение оказалось верным, на справочном форуме говорят, что в хроме нет и не было автоматического сохранения по ctrl+s  (см. ответ).

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl+s` выполняет функцию *Сохранить как*, поэтому у вас независимо от положения этой настройки будет спрашивать в какое месте вам сохранить файл. Эта настройка распространяется только на функцию *Сохранить*. И для того чтобы место сохранения не уточнялось, функцию необходимо отключить.

Answer (score 0):

В Chrome это невозможно.

В яндекс браузере есть ["умная" строка с кнопкой сохранения открытых файлов и страница помощи с описанием сохранения файлов открытых для просмотра](https://yandex.ru/support/browser/working-with-files/download-files.html#upload-file-open-viewing), в chrome нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вероятнее всего в яндексе <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> является частью надстройки, при нажатии вызывается тот же функционал для скачивания файлов, который вызывается при нажатии на кнопку <kbd>сохранить</kbd> из умной строки.

**UPD:** [пояснили на справочном форуме](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome-ru/t9ZHZwSLu08/f7_Ra2h7BAAJ):

> эту функцию они реализовали посредством обращения команды к их серверу
>   через JS, то есть это локальная реализация самого сайта

Comment: Что, даже плагин для хрома мне придется писать самому? Готовых решений нет? Кому вообще нужен такой браузер? Точно не человеку, который любит открывать кучу вкладок с картинками и прожимать комбо из `ctrl+s`>`ctrl+w`

Comment: У меня в Хроме ctrl + s работает так как хотел бы автор, но в чем разница не понимаю.

Comment: @AdamHodovanets у Вас чистая v.62 stable ? м.б. стоит какое-нибудь расширение одной из опций которого и есть нужная автору?

Comment: @Alex Из расширений только Grammarly(почти уверен, что там нет такой функции) и стандартные гугловские. Если автору интерестно могу создать учетку хрома и дать ему доступ может, что то изменится.

Comment: @AdamHodovanets если можете сделайте стороннюю учетку хрома и дайте доступ, весьма любопытно, т.к. на текущий момент все с кем мы общались в один голос утверждают, что такого быть не может (win10, chrome 62 stable).

Comment: Login: testingTestStackOverFlow@gmail.com



Pass: testingTestStackOverFlow123

Comment: @AdamHodovanets не работает, при нажатии ctrl+s появляется окно для выбора директории для сохранения. Не увидели указанного Вами расширения, Вы синхронизировали настройки браузера с аккаунтом?

Comment: @TryCatch вы можете поискать в [расширениях](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=ru) или можете [обратиться](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315) с предложением о внедрение такой функции.

Comment: @Alex первое что я сделал после того, как обнаружил такое поведение браузера - сообщил о проблеме через раздел "помощь". Я очень крепко уверен в том, что такое поведение - не норма. Я помню как когда-то использовал chrome и все работало круто. Да и AdamHodovanets говорит что у него все работает так же. Поэтому я уверен в том, что это какая-то ошибка и её возможно исправить (хотя бы через костыль)

Comment: @TryCatch [с пользователем гугла от AdamHodovanets окно все равно появлялось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746190#comment1154104_749380) . Вы можете сами попробовать, доступ есть. На справочном форуме тоже говорят, что так всегда было.

Comment: @AdamHodovanets попробуйте зайти с новой(чистой) учетной записи на пк. После этого зайдите в хром только под тестовым профилем(без предварительного входа в реальный профиль). Все еще можете сохранить файл по ctrl+s без открытия окна для выбора директории ?

Comment: @AdamHodovanets синхронизируйте настройки браузера с тестовым аккаунтом или запишите видео, где сохраняете [любую картинку](https://pp.userapi.com/c836333/v836333001/31189/8To0r3d-6iQ.jpg), что бы доказать что у вас при сохранении по `ctrl+s` не выскакивает диалоговое окно. Это было бы серьёзным аргументом в пользу того, что я это не придумал и у кого-то кроме меня сохранение работает так же

Comment: @AdamHodovanets уточните пожалуйста Вы сможете это сделать ?

Comment: @TryCatch возможно  Вас были установлены расширения или иные программы. на текущий момент мы так и не получили подтверждение от участника, что ctrl+s когда либо работало так как Вы написали.